# mpec.nl solver does not consider complementarity constraint in pyomo

Tags: pyomo

My model includes some complementarity constraints. But, I do not know why mpec.nl does not consider these constraints. The model gets solved with optimal status but at the end by checking the obtained values for the variables, I see the multiplication of complimetarity terms is not zero (Please refer to the end of the code). Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np
from pyomo.environ import *
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.opt import ProblemFormat
from Dijkstra import ReturnPai 
from pyomo.mpec import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverStatus, TerminationCondition
import timeit 




NN=['do1','do2','1','2','3','4','5','dd']    
II=['1','2','3','4','5']
Des=['5']
DO=['do1','do2']
DDes=['dd']
KK=['HDV','AV']
HH=list(range(14))


LL=[('do1','1'),('do2','2'),('1','2'),('2','3'),('1','3'),('3','4'),('3','5'),('4','5'),('5','dd')]


NV_K={'HDV':6,'AV':6}     # The number of vehicles
NP_P={'do1':20,'do2':25}   # The number of passenger
Sigma_K={'HDV':0,'AV':1}
hlength=1

Teta_SD=15   # Unit cost for Solo drivers
Teta_RD=10   # Unit cost for ridesharing drivers
Teta_RP=5    # Unit cost for Ridesharing passengers
Teta_np=500  # Unit cost for waiting passengers
B_AV=3       # The total number of passenger in AVs 
B_HDV=4      # The total number of passenger in HDVs 
beta=1.28    # The rpoportion
eta=0.5      # Meeting elasticities 
A0=0.5       # Caliberation
epsilon2=pow(10,-3)


Tau_0={('do1','1'):0,('do2','2'):0,('1','2'):3,
       ('2','3'):1,('1','3'):4,('3','4'):2,('3','5'):2,('4','5'):1,('5','dd'):0}


ghead={'do1':0,'do2':0,'1':3,'2':1,'3':2,'4':1,'5':0,'dd':0}
gbeforehead={'do1':0,'do2':0,'1':0,'2':0,'3':1,'4':2,'5':1,'dd':0}
PAI ={'1':4,'2':3,'3':2,'4':1,'do1':4,'do2':5,'5':0,'dd':0}


gh={}
gomegah={}
for (i,j) in LL:
    gh[i,j]=Tau_0[i,j]/hlength
    gomegah[i,j]= 2*gh[i,j]
    


gh_min={}
for i in NN:
    if i not in DDes:
        gh_min[i] = 99999
        for j in II:
            if (i,j) in LL and Tau_0[i,j]/hlength < gh_min[i]:
                gh_min[i]=Tau_0[i,j]/hlength
                
for i in NN:
    if i not in DDes:
        if gh_min[i]==99999:
            gh_min[i]=0

        
        
gomegah_min={}
for j in NN:
    if j not in DO:
        gomegah_min[j] = 99999
        for i in NN:
            if (i,j) in LL and (2*Tau_0[i,j])/hlength < gomegah_min[j]:
                gomegah_min[j]=(2*Tau_0[i,j])/hlength                

for j in NN:
    if j not in DO:
        if  gomegah_min[j] == 99999:
            gomegah_min[j]=0
    
gg={}
for i in NN:
    if i not in DDes:
        gg[i]=len(HH)-gh_min[i]   
    


    
C_Full_0={('do1','1','HDV'):10000, ('do1','1','AV'):10000,
        ('do2','2','HDV'):10000, ('do2','2','AV'):10000,
        ('5','dd','HDV'):10000,  ('5','dd','AV'):10000,
        ('1','2','HDV'):15,('1','2','AV'):16,
        ('2','3','HDV'):12,('2','3','AV'):13,
        ('1','3','HDV'):11,('1','3','AV'):14,
        ('3','4','HDV'):9,('3','4','AV'):11,
        ('3','5','HDV'):5,('3','5','AV'):8,
        ('4','5','HDV'):7,('4','5','AV'):10}    


C_Full={}
C_Full_HDV={}
C_Full_AV={}
for i in NN:
    for j in NN:
        for k in KK:
            if (i,j) in LL:
                C_Full[i,j,k]= C_Full_0[i,j,k]*0.5 
                if k=='HDV':
                    C_Full_HDV[i,j]=C_Full[i,j,k]
                else:
                    C_Full_AV[i,j]=C_Full[i,j,k]


Q={}
for i in NN:
    for j in NN:
        if (i,j) in LL:
            for k in KK:
                Q[i,j,k]= C_Full[i,j,k]*(gh[i,j]+gomegah[i,j])






np={}
nv={}
p_k1={}
p_solo={}
p_rs={}


for e in HH:
    for k in KK:
        if e==0:
            for i in DO:
                np[i,e] = NP_P[i]
                nv[k,e] = NV_K[k]
        else:
            for i in DO:
                np[i,e] = hlength*(-1*(p_solo[i,e-1]+(B_AV*sum(p_k1[i,j,'AV',e-1] for j in NN if (i,j) in LL))+B_HDV*p_rs[i,e-1] )) + np[i,e-1]
            if k=='AV':
                nv[k,e] = hlength*(-sum(p_k1[i,j,"AV",e-1] for i in DO for j in NN if (i,j) in LL) )+ nv[k,e-1]
            else:
                nv[k,e] = hlength*(-sum(p_solo[i,e-1]+p_rs[i,e-1] for i in DO for j in NN if (i,j) in LL))+ nv[k,e-1]
            
        # for i in DO:
        #     if np[i,e] <0:
        #         np[i,e]=0
        
        if nv[k,e]<0:
            nv[k,e]=0     
              
        for i in DO:          
            for j in NN:
                if (i,j) in LL:
                    p_k1[i,j,k,e]= A0*(.1*nv[k,e]+.1*np[i,e])
                   
                    if np[i,e] ==0 or nv[k,e]==0 or e>=7:
                        p_k1[i,j,k,e]= 0 
            if k == "HDV":
                p_rs[i,e]= sum(p_k1[i,j,k,e] for j in NN if (i,j) in LL)
            else:
                p_solo[i,e]=.1*(p_rs[i,e]+sum(p_k1[i,j,k,e] for j in NN  if (i,j) in LL))



#-------------Variables in  The Differential Complementarity Problem Model -----------------------
model = ConcreteModel(name='DCP')
ValidVarsIJH = [(i,j,e) for (i,j) in LL for e in HH]
ValidVarsIJKH = [(i,j,k,e) for (i,j) in LL for e in HH for k in KK]

model.Tau=Var(ValidVarsIJH, domain=NonNegativeReals, name= 'Tau', initialize=0)
for (i,j) in LL:
    for e in HH:
        model.Tau[i,j,e].setlb(Tau_0[i,j]) 


model.q_d=Var(ValidVarsIJH, domain=NonNegativeReals, name= 'q_d', initialize=0)
model.q_u=Var(ValidVarsIJH, domain=NonNegativeReals, name= 'q_u', initialize=0)
model.Q_cap=Var(ValidVarsIJH, domain=NonNegativeReals, name= 'Q_cap', initialize=0)
model.Gamma_Q=Var(ValidVarsIJH, domain=NonNegativeReals, name= 'Gamma_Q', initialize=0)
model.Gamma_C=Var(ValidVarsIJH, domain=NonNegativeReals, name= 'Gamma_C', initialize=0)
model.Delta=Var(ValidVarsIJH, domain=NonNegativeReals, name= 'Delta', initialize=0)
model.Deltabar=Var(ValidVarsIJH, domain=NonNegativeReals, name= 'Deltabar', initialize=0)
model.C=Var(ValidVarsIJH, domain=NonNegativeReals,name= 'C')

for (i,j) in LL:
    for e in HH:
       model.C[i,j,e].setlb(C_Full_HDV[i,j]) 
       model.C[i,j,e].setub(C_Full_AV[i,j]) 
       
model.rho=Var(ValidVarsIJH, domain=NonNegativeReals, bounds=(0,1), name= 'rho', initialize=0)
model.p=Var(ValidVarsIJH, domain=NonNegativeReals, name= 'p', initialize=0)
model.v=Var(ValidVarsIJH, domain=NonNegativeReals, name= 'v', initialize=0)
model.phi=Var(ValidVarsIJH, domain=NonNegativeReals, name='phi', initialize=0)
model.Bin=Var(ValidVarsIJH, domain=Binary, name='Bin',initialize=0)

model.pi_k=Var(NN,KK,HH, domain=NonNegativeReals,  name='pi_k' )


model.n=Var(ValidVarsIJKH,domain=NonNegativeReals, name='n', initialize=0)
model.p_k=Var(ValidVarsIJKH,domain=NonNegativeReals, name='p_k', initialize=0)
model.v_k=Var(ValidVarsIJKH,domain=NonNegativeReals, name='v_k', initialize=0)
model.q_dk=Var(ValidVarsIJKH,domain=NonNegativeReals, name='q_dk', initialize=0)
model.q_uk=Var(ValidVarsIJKH,domain=NonNegativeReals, name='q_uk', initialize=0)
model.toll=Var(ValidVarsIJKH,domain=NonNegativeReals, name='toll',initialize=0)




for i in NN:
    for k in KK:
        for e in HH:
            if i in Des or i in DDes:
                model.pi_k[i,k,e].fix(0)
            # else:
            #     model.pi_k[i,k,e].setlb(PAI[i]*(1-epsilon2) )
            if e>len(HH)-ghead[i]-1:
                model.pi_k[i,k,e].set_value(PAI[i]) 
                

for (i,j) in LL:
    for k in KK:
        for e in HH:
            if e>len(HH)-gh[i,j]-1:
                model.p_k[i,j,k,e].fix(0)
                
            # if e<gh[i,j]:
            #     model.v_k[i,j,k,e].fix(0)
                
            if e<=gh[i,j]-1:
                model.Deltabar[i,j,e].fix(0)
                model.Delta[i,j,e].fix(0)
            
            if e<=gbeforehead[i]-1:
               model.Gamma_C[i,j,e].fix(0)
               model.Gamma_Q[i,j,e].fix(0)
               
            if e==len(HH)-1:
               model.q_dk[i,j,k,e].fix(0) 
            
            if j in DDes:
                model.Delta[i,j,e].fix(0)
                model.Deltabar[i,j,e].fix(0)
                model.Gamma_C[i,j,e].fix(0)
                model.Gamma_Q[i,j,e].fix(0)

                
            if i in DO:
               model.q_uk[i,j,k,e].fix(0) 
               model.Gamma_C[i,j,e].fix(0)
               model.Gamma_Q[i,j,e].fix(0)
            if i not in DO and e==0:
               model.q_dk[i,j,k,e].fix(0)

    

#---------The Differential Complementarity Model

# expr=sum(model.q_d[i,j,e] for (i,j) in LL for e in HH)

# model.Obj = Objective(expr = expr, sense=minimize,name='Obj')


model.matching_AV=ConstraintList(name="matching_AV")
model.matching_HDV=ConstraintList(name="matching_HDV")
model.FC_dummy=Constraint(pyo.Any)

for (i,j) in LL:
      if i in DO:
        for e in HH:
            model.matching_AV.add(expr=model.p_k[(i,j,"AV",e)]==p_k1[(i,j,"AV",e)])           
            model.matching_HDV.add(expr=model.p_k[(i,j,"HDV",e)]==p_solo[(i,e)]+p_rs[(i,e)])
        for k in KK:
            model.FC_dummy[i+','+j+','+k]=model.p_k[(i,j,k,0)]==model.v_k[(i,j,k,0)] 



model.N_Vehicles_link_0  = ConstraintList(name = 'N_Vehicles_link_0') 
model.N_Vehicles_link_e = ConstraintList(name = 'N_Vehicles_link_e') 

for (i,j) in LL:
    for e in HH:
        for k in KK:
            if e==0:
                model.N_Vehicles_link_0.add(expr=model.n[(i,j,k,e)] == hlength*(model.p_k[(i,j,k,e)]-model.v_k[(i,j,k,e)]))
            else:    
                model.N_Vehicles_link_e.add(expr=model.n[(i,j,k,e)]-model.n[(i,j,k,e-1)] == hlength*(model.p_k[(i,j,k,e)]-model.v_k[(i,j,k,e)]))



model.DownstreamQL0=ConstraintList(name = 'DownstreamQL0') 
model.DownstreamQL00=ConstraintList(name='DownstreamQL00')
model.DownstreamQL1_k=ConstraintList(name='DownstreamQL1_k')
model.DownstreamQL2_k=ConstraintList(name='DownstreamQL2_k')
model.DownstreamQL3_k=ConstraintList(name='DownstreamQL3_k')

for (i,j) in LL:
    for e in HH:
        for k in KK:
            if i in DO:
                if e<=1:
                    model.DownstreamQL0.add(expr= model.q_dk[(i,j,k,e)]==hlength*(model.p_k[(i,j,k,e)]-model.v_k[(i,j,k,e)])) 
                elif e>=2:
                    model.DownstreamQL00.add(expr=model.q_dk[(i,j,k,e)]-model.q_dk[(i,j,k,e-1)]==hlength*(model.p_k[(i,j,k,e)]-model.v_k[(i,j,k,e)]) )
            else:
                if e==0:
                    model.DownstreamQL1_k.add(expr= model.q_dk[(i,j,k,e)]==hlength*(-model.v_k[(i,j,k,e)]))
                elif e<=gh[i,j]-1 and e>=1:
                    model.DownstreamQL2_k.add(expr= model.q_dk[(i,j,k,e)]-model.q_dk[(i,j,k,e-1)]==hlength*(-model.v_k[(i,j,k,e)]))
                else:
                    model.DownstreamQL3_k.add(expr= model.q_dk[(i,j,k,e)]-model.q_dk[(i,j,k,e-1)]==hlength*(model.p_k[(i,j,k,e-gh[(i,j)])]-model.v_k[(i,j,k,e)]) )


      

model.FC = ConstraintList(name = 'FC')
for i in NN:
    if not (i in DDes or i in DO):
        for e in HH:
              if e<=len(HH)-ghead[i]-1:
                for k in KK:
                    expr1 = sum(model.p_k[(i,j,k,e)] for j in NN if (i,j) in LL and e<=len(HH)-gh[(i,j)]-1)
                    expr2=sum(model.v_k[(j,i,k,e)] for j in NN if (j,i) in LL and e>=gh[(j,i)])
                    if not (type(expr1+expr2) == int or type(expr1+expr2)==float): 
                        model.FC.add(expr= expr1-expr2 == 0)
            
                        
model.Total_Inflow=ConstraintList(name = 'Total_Inflow') 
model.Total_Exitflow=ConstraintList(name = 'Total_Exitflow') 
for (i,j) in LL:
    for e in HH:
        model.Total_Inflow.add(expr=model.p[(i,j,e)]==sum(model.p_k[(i,j,k,e)] for k in KK))
        model.Total_Exitflow.add(expr=model.v[(i,j,e)]==sum(model.v_k[(i,j,k,e)] for k in KK))

 


model.UpstreamQL_0_k=ConstraintList(name='UpstreamQL_0_k')
model.UpstreamQL_1_k=ConstraintList(name='UpstreamQL_1_k')
model.UpstreamQL_2_k=Constraint(pyo.Any)

#model.UpstreamQL_2_k=ConstraintList(name='UpstreamQL_2_k')

for (i,j) in LL:
    if not i in DO:
        for k in KK:
            for e in HH:
                if e==0:
                    model.UpstreamQL_0_k.add(expr=model.q_uk[(i,j,k,e)]==hlength*model.p_k[(i,j,k,e)])
                elif e<=gomegah[i,j]-1 and e>=1:
                    model.UpstreamQL_1_k.add(expr=model.q_uk[(i,j,k,e)]-model.q_uk[(i,j,k,e-1)]==hlength*model.p_k[(i,j,k,e)])
                elif e>=gomegah[i,j]:
                    model.UpstreamQL_2_k['UpstreamQL_2_k('+i+','+j+','+k+','+str(e)+')']= model.q_uk[(i,j,k,e)]-model.q_uk[(i,j,k,e-1)]==hlength*(model.p_k[(i,j,k,e)]-model.v_k[i,j,k,e-gomegah[(i,j)]])



model.TotalDownstreamQL=ConstraintList(name='TotalDownstreamQL')
model.TotalUpstreamQL=ConstraintList(name='TotalUpstreamQL')

for (i,j) in LL:
    for e in HH:
        model.TotalDownstreamQL.add(expr=model.q_d[(i,j,e)]==sum(model.q_dk[(i,j,k,e)] for k in KK))
        model.TotalUpstreamQL.add(expr=model.q_u[(i,j,e)]==sum(model.q_uk[(i,j,k,e)] for k in KK))




model.ExitflowRate=ConstraintList(name='ExitflowRate')
for (i,j) in LL:
    if not j in DDes:
        for e in HH:
            if e>=gh[i,j]:
                model.ExitflowRate.add(expr=sum(model.v_k[(i,j,k,e)] for k in KK) == model.C[(i,j,e)]-model.phi[(i,j,e)]-model.Deltabar[(i,j,e)])



model.Comp_Downstream_LB=ComplementarityList(name='Comp_Downstream_LB')

for  (i,j) in LL:
    for e in HH:
      model.Comp_Downstream_LB.add(expr=complements(0<=model.phi[i,j,e],model.q_d[i,j,e]>=0))



model.Comp_delta=ComplementarityList(name='Comp_delta')
for (i,j) in LL:
    if not j in  DDes:
        for e in HH:
            if e>=gh[i,j]:
                model.Comp_delta.add(expr=complements( 0<=model.Delta[i,j,e],model.Delta[(i,j,e)] - model.Deltabar[(i,j,e)]>=0))
        




model.Comp_inflowwithheld_Q=ComplementarityList(name='Comp_inflowwithheld_Q')

for (i,j) in LL:
    if not i in DO:
        for e in HH:
            if e>=gbeforehead[(i)]:
                model.Comp_inflowwithheld_Q.add(expr=complements(0<=model.Gamma_C[i,j,e],(model.Q_cap[(i,j,e)]-hlength*(sum(model.p_k[(i,j,k,s)] for k in KK for s in HH  if s<=e and s<=gomegah[i,j]-1)+ sum(
                          model.p_k[(i,j,k,s)]-model.v_k[(i,j,k,s-gomegah[(i,j)])] for k in KK for s in HH  if s<=e and s>=gomegah[i,j]))>= 0)))


model.Comp_inflowwithheld_C=ComplementarityList(name='Comp_inflowwithheld_C')
for (i,j) in LL:
    if not i in DO or not j in DDes:
        for e in HH:
            if e>=gbeforehead[(i)]:
                model.Comp_inflowwithheld_C.add(expr=complements(0<=model.Gamma_C[i,j,e],model.C[i,j,e]-model.p[i,j,e]>=0))


model.Comp_inflowwithheld_T=ComplementarityList(name='Comp_inflowwithheld_T')


for (i,j) in LL:
    if not j in DDes:
        for e in HH:
            if e>=gh[i,j]:
                model.Comp_inflowwithheld_T.add(expr=complements(0<=model.v[(i,j,e)],sum(model.Gamma_Q[(j,m,e)]+model.Gamma_C[(j,m,e)] for m in NN if (j,m) in LL)-sum(model.Delta[(ii,j,e)] for ii in NN if (ii,j) in LL if ii<i) - model.Deltabar[(i,j,e)] >= 0))

#----------------nonlinear--------------
model.Rho1=ConstraintList(name='Rho1')
model.Rho2=ConstraintList(name='Rho2')

for (i,j) in LL:
    for e in HH:
        if e>=1:
            model.Rho1.add(expr=model.rho[(i,j,e)]<=model.n[(i,j,"AV",e)]/(model.n[(i,j,"HDV",e)]+model.n[(i,j,"AV",e)]+.0001)+.0001)
            model.Rho2.add(expr=model.rho[(i,j,e)]>=model.n[(i,j,"AV",e)]/(model.n[(i,j,"HDV",e)]+model.n[(i,j,"AV",e)]+.0001)-.0001)



model.LinkCap1=ConstraintList(name='LinkCap1')
model.LinkCap2=ConstraintList(name='LinkCap2')

for (i,j) in LL:
    for e in HH:
        
          model.LinkCap1.add(expr=model.C[(i,j,e)]  <= ((C_Full[(i,j,'HDV')]*C_Full[(i,j,'AV')])/(C_Full[(i,j,'AV')]+model.rho[(i,j,e)]*(C_Full[(i,j,'HDV')]-C_Full[(i,j,'AV')]))+.0001)+.0001)
          model.LinkCap2.add(expr=model.C[(i,j,e)]  >= ((C_Full[(i,j,'HDV')]*C_Full[(i,j,'AV')])/(C_Full[(i,j,'AV')]+model.rho[(i,j,e)]*(C_Full[(i,j,'HDV')]-C_Full[(i,j,'AV')]))+.0001)-.0001)


model.QueueCap_0=ConstraintList(name='QueueCap_0')
model.QueueCap_1=ConstraintList(name='QueueCap_1')
model.QueueCap_2=ConstraintList(name='QueueCap_2')
model.QueueCap_3=ConstraintList(name='QueueCap_3')
model.QueueCap_4=ConstraintList(name='QueueCap_4')

for (i,j) in LL:
    if not i in DO:
        for e in HH:
     
            model.QueueCap_0.add(expr=model.Q_cap[(i,j,e)]<=((model.n[(i,j,"AV",e)]+model.n[(i,j,"HDV",e)])*Q[(i,j,"HDV")])/(((1/beta)*model.n[(i,j,"AV",e)])+model.n[(i,j,"HDV",e)]+0.00001)+(1-model.Bin[(i,j,e)])*Q[(i,j,"AV")])

            model.QueueCap_2.add(expr= model.n[(i,j,"AV",e)]+model.n[(i,j,"HDV",e)]<=sum(NV_K[(k)] for k in KK)*model.Bin[(i,j,e)])
            
            model.QueueCap_3.add(expr=model.Q_cap[(i,j,e)]<=0.5*(Q[(i,j,"HDV")]+Q[(i,j,"AV")])+(model.Bin[(i,j,e)]*Q[(i,j,"AV")]))

                    


model.Tau_Cal=ConstraintList(name='Tau')
for (i,j) in LL:
    if not j in DDes:
        for e in HH:
            if e>=1 and e<=len(HH)-gh[i,j]-1:
                model.Tau_Cal.add(expr=model.Tau[(i,j,e)]== Tau_0[(i,j)]
                                +((model.q_d[(i,j,e+gh[(i,j)])]/model.C[(i,j,e)])*
                                              (1+((model.phi[(i,j,e+gh[(i,j)])]+model.Deltabar[(i,j,e+gh[(i,j)])])/(model.C[(i,j,e)])))))
 



model.demandsatisfaction=ConstraintList(name='demandsatisfaction')

for k in KK:
    model.demandsatisfaction.add(expr=sum(model.p_k[(i,j,k,e)] for (i,j) in LL  for e in HH if i in DO )==sum(model.v_k[(m,ii,k,e)] for (m,ii) in LL for e in HH if ii in DDes ))

Start=timeit.default_timer()



TransformationFactory('mpec.nl').apply_to(model)

solver = SolverFactory('ipopt') 
solver.options["max_iter"]=100000

result=solver.solve(model, tee=True)


# #-----------------------
if (result.solver.status == SolverStatus.ok) and (result.solver.termination_condition == TerminationCondition.optimal):
    for (i,j) in LL:
        if not i in DO or not j in DDes:
            for e in HH:
                if e>=gbeforehead[(i)]:
                    if (model.Gamma_C[i,j,e]())*(model.C[i,j,e]()-model.p[i,j,e]())>0.000001:
                        print(i,j,k,e)
#-----------------------------------



End=timeit.default_timer()

Run_Time=End-Start
print('Time: ', Run_Time)
```